# Using SwipeCards with a Custom Adapter is not displaying some values?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout, android-asynctask

I am using the Swipecards project from here: https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards and I've created a custom adapter to use with my own object rather than the simple ArrayAdapter since I need some extra fields, however, not all of my custom fields are showing up on the swipecard.

With the following code, the title, company name and description fields are correctly populated onto my card but not the others, even though the fields are there. No errors from the debugger and everything works fine but the fields are just not populated with data!!! What am I missing?

Here is what I am doing in my activity:

At the top of the activity:

```
@InjectView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;
```

In my AsyncTask:

```
arrayAdapter = new JobAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.jobcard,      result);
flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Yes: the result ArrayList is populated with values.

My adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService((Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));

        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            //row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_jobTitle);
            holder.payrate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_payRate);
            holder.startdate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_startDate);
            holder.workinghrs = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);
            holder.location = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            holder.companyname = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_companyName);
            holder.description = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_JobDesc);
            holder.equipment = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_equipmentReq);
            holder.experience = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_experienceReq);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Job j = jobs.get(0);

        holder.title.setText(j.getJobTitle());
        holder.payrate.setText(j.getPayrate());
        holder.startdate.setText(j.getDurationStart());
        holder.workinghrs.setText(j.getWorkingHrs());
        holder.location.setText(j.getLocation());
        holder.companyname.setText("ABC Company");
        holder.description.setText(j.getDescription());
        holder.equipment.setText("Hardhat");
        holder.experience.setText("3-5 years");

        return row;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title;
        TextView payrate;
        TextView startdate;
        TextView workinghrs;
        TextView location;
        TextView companyname;
        TextView description;
        TextView equipment;
        TextView experience;
    }
```

And finally, my jobcard.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainCardLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_jobTitle"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#474747"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="Cement Pouring Guy"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_companyName"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#474747"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="ABC Company"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_experienceReq"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                tools:text="3-5 years" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                tools:text="Langley, BC" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_payRate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                tools:text="125/day" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_JobDesc"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#474747"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            tools:text="Pour Cement, Mix Cement, Level Cement and go pick up cement bags."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/additionalInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_startDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                tools:text="June 1, 2016" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                tools:text="8h" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_equipmentReq"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                tools:text="Hardhat" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_swipe_left_indicator"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#A5F" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/item_swipe_right_indicator"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#5AF" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks for the help!